# Swap column x of tab-separated values file with column x of second tsv file

Tags: linux, bash, csv

Let's say I have:

file1.tsv

```
Foo\tBar\tabc\t123
Bla\tWord\tabc\tqwer
Blub\tqwe\tasd\tqqq
```

file2.tsv

```
123\tzxcv\tAAA\tqaa
asd\t999\tBBB\tdef
qwe\t111\tCCC\tabc
```

And I want to overwrite column 3 of file1.tsv with column 3 of file2.tsv to end up with:

```
Foo\tBar\tAAA\t123
Bla\tWord\tBBB\tqwer
Blub\tqwe\tCCC\tqqq
```

What would be a good way to do this in bash?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$3;next}{$3=a[FNR]}1' OFS='\t' file{2,1}.tsv > output.tsv
```

---

If you want to use just `bash`, with little more effort:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r a1 a2 _ a4; do
    IFS=$'\t' read -ru3 _ _ b3 _
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$a1" "$a2" "$b3" "$a4"
done <file1.tsv 3<file2.tsv >output.tsv
```

**Output:**

```
Foo     Bar     AAA     123
Bla     Word    BBB     qwer
Blub    qwe     CCC     qqq
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this can be, with correction as pointed out by @PesaThe:

```
paste -d$'\t' <(cut -d$'\t' -f1,2 file1.tsv) <(cut -d$'\t' -f3 file2.tsv) <(cut -d$'\t' -f4 file1.tsv)
```

The output will be:

```
Foo     Bar     AAA     123
Bla     Word    BBB     qwer
Blub    qwe     CCC     qqq
```

Comment: Your `cut` commands split on the character `t`. Try input: `1t23\tabc...`. I believe OP has tabs in his input, not literal `\t` anyway, so you could use `$'\t'` instead :)

Comment: @PesaThe thanks for pointing that out, made required edits. :)